# Attachment does not display in a rich text field

Tags: xpages

I've two rich text fields in notes documents and both have attachments. I'm using xpage for this document with file upload and download control for both rich text fields.

Attachment is displayed for download in first field but second field's download control does not display the attachment.

What is issue?

Comment: Please add sample source code here.

Comment: There are two kinds of attachments: at the document level or field level. Best tool to fix issues like this is standard Lotus Notes client and proper form to open the document. Hint: document level attachments are shown "bottomlined" in Notes client.

Comment: Thanks. I've created an agent in lotusscript to move attachment from bottom to the proper rich text field and it was working fine in the beginning. There are two rich text fields. In old version, user's attachment was attached in 1st field but for 2nd field, the attachment was attached at the bottom. Recently we upgraded to 8.5.3FP6 and found that 2nd field attachment was going directly into field. Because of upgrade, the agent started to create duplicate attachment in the same field and they were all visible on the web. I created an agent to remove these duplicates but nothing was seen on web

Comment: As 2nd field is attaching file correctly, there is no need of running agent. Now the attachments are seen properly in the 2nd field without help of back ground agent. Thanks everybody.